# Spring database transaction not committing data in Db

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I have created a project with spring boot. I have hikariConfig to create the data source for connection pooling with the autocommmit property set as false. Doing batch insert with jdbcTemplate running inside method annotated with @Transaction for DataSourceTransactionManager. I am unable to see the data getting inserted in Db after the program execution. If I make the autocommit true in hikariconfig it works fine.

```
@SpringBootApplication

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

@Component

@EnableTransactionManagement

public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean (name = "dateSourceForSqlServer")

    public DataSource dataSourceForSqlServer () {

        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setConnectionTimeout(10000L);
        hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(10000L);
        hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(1);
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(1);
       hikariConfig.setMaxLifetime(600000L);
        hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("select 1");
        hikariConfig.setValidationTimeout(4000L);


        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=invt_mgmt");
        hikariConfig.setUsername("sa");
        hikariConfig.setPassword("sql_server_pass_123");

         hikariConfig.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");


    hikariConfig.setAutoCommit(false);

        return  new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    }

    @Bean (name = "jdbcTemplateForSqlServer")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateForSqlServer () {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
        jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(dataSourceForSqlServer());

        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "invtMgmtTxMangerForSqlServer")
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        DataSourceTransactionManager manager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
        manager.setDataSource(dataSourceForSqlServer());
        return manager;
    }

}


@Component

public class startBean {

    @Autowired
    private Business Business;

    @PostConstruct
    public void startApp() throws SQLException {
        Business.insertContainerHierarchy();
        Business.insertContainerHierarchy();

    }
}

@Component

 class public Business {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jdbcTemplateForSqlServer")
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateForSqlServer;

    String insertIntStudent = "INSERT INTO student (id, name) Values(?, ?)";

    @Transactional(value = "invtMgmtTxMangerForSqlServer")
    public void insertContainerHierarchy () throws SQLException {

      System.out.println(TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
      System.out.println(TransactionSynchronizationManager.getCurrentTransactionName());


        Date start = new Date();

        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            jdbcTemplateForSqlServer.batchUpdate(insertIntStudent, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

                @Override
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                   ps.setInt(1, i);
                   ps.setString(2, String.valueOf(i));
                }

                @Override
                public int getBatchSize() {
                    return 1000;
                }
            });
        }
        System.out.println(new Date().getTime() - start.getTime());
    } 

}
```

I have used `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()` which is returing true when the method is executed.

Q1. Why the data is not getting inserted, Transaction is supposed to autocommit once the method is executed?

Q2. In case spring transaction is getting used will database connection autocommit value make any difference?

Q3. How currently I am able to insert with autocommit set to true?

Comment: At a glance, the example code looks a bit weird.  You have a loop with 500 iterations, but you are using a BatchPreparedStatementSetter with a batch size of 1000 (which means the setValues will be called 1000 times).  Are you really trying to insert 500 x 1000 = 500,000 rows?  And when the for loop iterates, the next set of inserts will presumably cause primary key violations on student.id.

Comment: No unique constraint either on id or name. Its a dummy project , I am looking for  the batch performance, So yes 500 * 1000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to invoke a transaction-wrapped proxy from within the `@PostConstruct` method. For that bean, all the initialization may be complete but not necessarily for the rest of the context. Not all proxies may be set at that point.

I would suggest implementing the `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` interface in order to trigger any data creation inside that class. This will ensure it will be called after the entire context has been set-up:

```
@Component
public class OnContextInitialized implements
  ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private Business Business;

    @Override public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        Business.insertContainerHierarchy();
        Business.insertContainerHierarchy();
    }
}
```

Comment: but System.out.println(TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());is giving true

Comment: looks like transaction has started , isnt the flag suggest that.